# Classic ASP SQL Parameterization - How Can I Remove Single Quotes From A Parameter?

Tags: sql, asp-classic, quotes, parameterized

I am using classic ASP with a parameterized SQL querystring as follows:

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE Category LIKE ? ORDER BY SubDate ?"
```

The SQL query string is being used in the following parameterized code:

```
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set rsView = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_connContent_STRING
cmd.Prepared = true
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.CommandText = SQL
cmd.CommandTimeout = 60

cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("Category", 202, adParamInput, 30, qFilter))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("SubDate", 202, adParamInput, 10, myDateSort))

rsView.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rsView.Open cmd, , adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
```

The code above works great except for one huge problem.  The "ORDER BY SubDate ?" part outputs "ORDER BY SubDate 'DESC'" where DESC has single quotes around it added due to the fact that it is a parameter.  I get a bad syntax error when running the code above because of the single quotes around DESC (which can also be ASC depending on what the user selects and sends through the URL query string).  It seems all SQL parameters are output with single quotes.  How can I remove the single quotes from specific SQL parameters so they don't create syntax errors in the SQL string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very uncommon to allow keywords (or identifiers for that matter) to be parameters. There is not a single framework that I know of that supports it.

Since there are only 2 allowable values, why don't you simply write:

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE Category LIKE ? ORDER BY SubDate "
If myDateSort = "ASC" Or myDateSort = "DESC" Then
    SQL = SQL & myDateSort
Else
    'whoops, value not allowed. raise error... 
End If
'...rest of your code...
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I'm trying to avoid SQL injection by going to parameterized queries.  Since myDateSort is a user defined variable passed through the URL string, I believe that a user could still modify my SQL query if I directly use the myDateSort variable outside of a parameter as shown in your code.  Is this correct?  Thanks again!

Comment: Actually, now I see that we are controlling the value assigned to myDateSort using the If function.  I suppose this would keep that value secure.

Comment: Ok, I've been thinking about your solution more.  Essentially, we are "sanitizing" the myDateSort variable using the If function.  My question now regarding your solution, why not just sanitize all user inputs instead of parametizing all my SQL queries?  Although, I've read many places that sanitization isn't enough.  What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: @user1531027, it is correct that the IF condition ensures only allowed values can be passed. If it makes you feel better, you could of course write `IF myDateSort = "ASC" Then SQL = SQL + "ASC" ElseIf myDateSort = "DESC" Then SQL = SQL + "DESC" Else ... End If` etc. but it would make exactly zero difference for the result.

Comment: @user1531027 Regarding parameters vs sanitizing input: contrary to popular belief, prepared statement parameters weren't originally designed to sanitize input. Rather the idea is that the RDBMS might be tasked with a similar query many or at least multiple times, and that resources and performance may be gained by parsing and planning a template for such a query just once. To execute such a template, values would have to be bound to value placeholders (the ?'s). This is also why parameters don't typically work for structural aspects of a query, like keywords and identifiers.

Comment: @user1531027 Regarding the question whether you should sanitize input for all parameters yourself: there is no theoretical reason why you shouldn't, it just turns out that in practice, it's harder than it seems and the ramifications can be quite serious if you get it wrong. However, it usually goes wrong for those inputs where the value range is arbitrarily large, esp. if the values are allowed to contain "special" characters. But In this particular case, there are exactly 2 known values that are allowed, and it's trivial to check for them.

Comment: Ok, I hammered down tonight and sanitized all of my variables embedded in my SQL strings.  You're correct, you really have to think about the characters you're blacklisting so as to not create problems.  Also, for me blacklisting made more sense than whitelisting.

Comment: I also now realize that if you want to protect against SQL injection attacks, proper sanitization is just as effective as parameterized SQL queries.  The only difference is parameterization doesn't require any thought about escape and illegal characters.  Also, thanks for the history on parameters, very cool.

Comment: In the end, it was a heck of a lot easier to sanitize my code.  I would like to do parameters but it's just too late in the game with this code.  Thanks for the help.