# SQL Procedure - Using a parameter as an operator

Tags: sql, parameters, equals, operator-keyword, procedural

I have a procedure which I am trying to get to select the results based on the value of a measure being above a stated parameter. However, I would like the greater than to be changable to equals or less than.

I have tried substituting the > for a parameter, but it gives me the error: 
    sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "PARAM_OP" (Where PARAM_OP is the name of the parameter which should be substituted for ther operator.

Any ideas would be welcome.

Code below:

```
var_out = 
SELECT
    "Col1" AS "Col1",
    "Col2" AS "Col2",
    "Col3" AS "Col3",
    SUM(Col4) AS "Col4"

FROM <schema>.<view>
WHERE "Col2" = PARAM_1
GROUP BY Col1, Col2, Col3
HAVING SUM(Col4) > PARAM_2
ORDER BY SUM(Col4);
```

Comment: Where does param_op go in this code?

Comment: Does one of your lines read:  
  

HAVING SUM(Col4) PARAM_OP PARAM_2  

If so you probably want to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: You can't use parameters for structural parts of SQL statements - so not for any keyword, operator, or identifier. Parameters can appear only where you'd expect a value expression. IOW Parameters are placeholders for values that get bound to a "real" value before query time. The solution is to generate the SQL statement in your application code, and execute that generated statement. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11518315/classic-asp-sql-parameterization-how-can-i-remove-single-quotes-from-a-paramet

Comment: Paddy - PARAM_OP would be substituting the > operator.

Comment: Aushin - How would this be created in Dynamic SQL? 
Roland / Holder - I'm using a Hana database, so I would rather have all the code generated serverside to utilise the processing power.

Answer (score 0):

I'm imagining something like.

```
DECLARE @Code VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @Code = 
'
var_out = 
SELECT
    "Col1" AS "Col1",
    "Col2" AS "Col2",
    "Col3" AS "Col3",
    SUM(Col4) AS "Col4"
FROM <schema>.<view>
WHERE "Col2" = ' + PARAM_1 + 
'GROUP BY Col1, Col2, Col3
HAVING SUM(Col4) ' + PARAM_OP + ' ' + PARAM_2 
+ 'ORDER BY SUM(Col4);'


EXEC sp_executesql @Code
```

So you build a string that looks like the SQL you wanted to execute and then you run the SQL string using whatever means your RDBMS provides for doing that.  In MSSQL, that would be sp_executesql